# Why does my rear wheel not spin and wobbles

Tags: rear-wheel, wobble

[image: rear wheel]Rear wheel doesn’t spin

The wheel doesn’t spin freely and wobbles and I checked the spokes

Comment: Need more detail and perhaps a video/photo. On the very limited information most likely suspect is a broken axle. (Wild guess, so not an answer)

Comment: alright how can I send you a video?

Comment: There is a way to add a video to your question by editing it. It would be one of the tools/options there.

Comment: How old is the bike?  It looks brand new ?   If the bike is faulty from new then take it back to the shop for a tune up, which should be free/covered by warranty.

Comment: the bike is like 2-1 year old but idk there is warranty

Comment: Dies the brake disk wobble and rub? If not, the problem is likely the wheel is out of true.  Does 'wobble' mean wheel moves loosely when stationary, or does it move side to side when spinning, but same point on wheel is always closest to one side.

Comment: so the wheel doesn’t move when you try to but when you pedal the wheel wobbles when it is spinning, the disc brakes I think are fine but I see a little rubbing

Comment: @William has it ever worked correctly?  Did you change anything ?

Comment: yeah it has when i got it

Answer (score 2):

I would start by removing the pegs - use a stout screwdriver as a lever, they're just really big nuts.  That will expose the real axle nuts and allow you to inspect closer.

Wiggle the top of the wheel left and right, and observe what moves and what is stationary.  There should be no(practically no) detectable play.

If that's okay, then spin the wheel and watch the rim relative to a nearby part of the frame.  If its the rim "wobbling" while you ride, then the rim is out of true and needs to be brought back to flat by methodically adjusting spokes.

If there is play in the area of the axle, it could be over-compressed by the wheel nuts and have the pre-load on the bearings too tight.

Once you narrow down on the problem area, we'll go into more detail.

Comment: I also have chain tensioners on my bike